# Motion of charged particle in em wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, oscillators

What is the direction of oscillation of a charged particle when an electromagnetic wave hits it?
I think it would in a circle whose plane is along the direction of em wave and perpendicular to magnetic field of wave.
Am I right?

Comment: What kind of system is the charged particle in? Is it an electron around an atom, or in free space, or a free electron in the conduction band of a (semi)metal?

Comment: @PhilH          In space held stationary at a place due to some unspecified forces, ie. There is no net force acting on it.

Comment: This is an incredibly complicated question, even for single particle motion experiencing only the effects of the fluctuating fields from the wave.  You can simplify things by assuming the particle has no effect on the wave (e.g., no "feedback" or emission of its own) but it's still not trivial (the Lorentz equation may be, but the particle trajectories need not be).  Generally, one would perform a numerical particle tracing simulation because the orbits can be very messy...

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83157/

Comment: https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/70253/PHPAEN-10-5-2155-1.pdf?sequence=2 This paper can solve your question. Eqn 13

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the problem up into two regimes: (Non-relativistic) where the charged particle velocity is $\ll c$ and the solution is simple, shown below. (Relativistic} where the non-relativistic assumption cannot be made and the solution is quite difficult.

**Non-relativistic.**
We say that
$$ m \frac{d^2 \vec{r}}{dt^2} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B}).$$
But for a plane wave in vacuum we know that $B = E/c$ and so the second term on the right hand side can be ignored.

So for example, if you have a plane wave travelling along the x-axis with amplitude $E_0$ and frequency $\omega$:
$$m \frac{d^2 \vec{r}}{dt^2} = qE_0 \sin (\omega t - kx) \vec{j},$$
where I have chosen to polarise the wave along the y-axis and the B-field is along the z-axis.

If we now assume the charged particle starts at rest and at the origin, then by integrating twice, we have
$$ \vec{r} = \frac{q E_0}{m \omega} \left( t - \frac{\sin \omega t}{\omega} \right) \vec{j}.$$

There is some second-order oscillation in the $x$ direction, at *twice* the frequency, but with a *much* smaller amplitude.

**Relativistic.** Much harder.

The *four* components of acceleration are:
$$m \ddot{x}  = -q\dot{y} B_0 \sin \omega t $$
$$m \ddot{y}  = q( \dot{x}B_0 \sin \omega t + \dot{t} E_0 \sin \omega t)$$
$$m \ddot{z} = 0$$
$$m \ddot{t} = \frac{q \dot{y}}{c}E_0 \sin \omega t $$
where the derivatives here are with respect to proper time $\tau$ and the relationship between proper time and coordinate time $t$ is
$$ d\tau = dt \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{c^2}\left[\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right) \right]^2 \right]^{1/2}$$

As you might expect, the results of integrating these are messy. The whole thing is gone through in [Kruger & Bovyn (1976)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/9/11/008/meta) and the results are expressed as functions of $\tau$ and the cyclotron frequency $\Omega = eB_0/m$ (equations 12a-d in that reference give general expressions for a plane wave excitation). However the results can be expressed in terms of a series expansion of harmonics of frequency $\omega^*$, where $\omega^*$ is related to $\omega$ by a doppler shift (see p. 1844 of the paper) - that is the oscillations can no longer be considered to be at a single frequency and take place in both the $x$ and $y$ directions.

Comment: Would you please explain where the last term in the set of "acceleration" comes from? I mean the equation with $m\ddot{t}$ in the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz force acting on a free charged particle in an em field ${\bf E},{\bf B}$ is ${\bf F} = q({\bf E} + {\bf v}\times{\bf B})$ and if you are using non-relativistic mechanics then you have to solve the equation $$m\frac{d {\bf v}}{dt} = q({\bf E} + {\bf v}\times{\bf B})$$ with (from your question I presume you mean a plane wave travelling in the $z$ direction)$${\bf E}= E_0{\bf i} sin(\omega t + kz), {{\bf B}= B_0{\bf j} sin(\omega t + kz)}$$

(it may be easier to keep the complex form for the em field, *i.e* replace $\sin$ by $e^{i(\omega t + k z)}$?). For a plane wave there will be a relationship between the amplitudes $E_0, B_0$ but usually the magnetic force term will be much smaller than the electric force term (certainly if you are assuming non-relativistic mechanics then this will be true).

To solve the problem for ${\bf v}$ you will need the initial conditions. In the simplest case that the charge at $t = 0$ is initially at rest at the origin I suspect that it may be easier looking for a numerical solution: When the charge is at rest it feels the force of the electric field which moves it in the direction ${\bf i}$ and then the magnetic force pushes it in the direction ${\bf i}\times{\bf j} = {\bf k}$ so that you have to take into account the variation with distance of the plane wave.

PS: Note that besides being non-relativistic it also ignores the charge (since it is accelerating) also radiates energy.

Comment: In free space, $B_{0} = E_{0}/c$ so yes, the $\mathbf{E}$ field is much more important for any everyday-Earth electric fields we are exposed to as $B_{0}$ is very small.